# Does Spring AMQP Automatically finds the detail of cluster of rabbitmq nodes?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

There is an `<address>` field in the `ConnectionFactory` of Spring AMQP, so I have to specify address of all the nodes in the cluster in that field or ican just write address of one node of the cluster and it can get details of other nodes automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the producer side, you can publish to any member of the cluster.

On the consumer side, if the queues are HA, then you can connect to any member of the cluster (to which the queue is mirrored). For non-mirrored queues you have to connect to the instance that owns the queue.

Providing a list of addresses to the connection factory is just for failover; the client will try to connect to each instance in the order they are provided.

**EDIT**

You can discover the cluster members by using the REST API (http-client jar)...

```
Client client = new Client("http://10.0.0.3:15672/api/", "guest", "guest");
System.out.println(client.getNodes());
```

The information doesn't include ip addresses, but the node names are usually `rabbit@host`.

Comment: If we have cluster of 3 nodes and we specify address of only  one node in the `<address>` field   and spring amqp connects to that node but after some time that  node fails so the spring amqp will automatically go the next node in the cluster ?

Comment: Only if you provide it with a list of addresses; the RabbitMQ client doesn't "discover" other nodes.

Comment: OK  sir , Then there is no way in Spring AMQP by which we can know details of the cluster because every time I add another node in the cluster so i have to change the client configuration